# Dynamic programming of a knapsack with additional constraints

Tags: optimization, dynamic-programming, knapsack-problem

If we have a normal 0-1 knapsack problem and want to solve it with dynamic programming, we use bottom up computation like explained [here](https://cw.fel.cvut.cz/wiki/_media/courses/ae4m33bia/dp_examples.pdf).

But how is a knapsack problem solved with dynamic programming, if you add constraints to the problem saying that some items are not allowed added together like the following constraint: x1 + x2 <= 1? Do you then use some sort of a third dimension on the table?